# How to show that a subgroup is normal.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of invertible $2\times 2$-matrices over the real numbers. Let $H \subseteq G$ be a group consisting of matrices with determinant equal to 1.

I'm to show that $H$ is a normal subgroup. I tried showing that $ghg^{-1}$ would end up with a determinant equal to 1, but that was just an awful lot of calculating. Then I thought perhaps I should find a group homomorphism $\phi: G \to G$ such that the kernel was the identity matrix. But I couldn't figure out how.

Any tips would be awesome.

Comment: Remember that $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$

Comment: Why $\phi :G \to G$, such that that kernel is *the identity matrix*? Your target group can be anything, and you want to re-think about what the kernel should be, to show that $H$ is normal in $G$ (but without results about the determinant, this route will be essentially the same amount of calculation).

Comment: so $det (ghg^{-1}) = det(g)det(h)det(g^{-1}) = det(h) = 1 \to ghg^{-1} \in H \to  H$ is a normal subgroup of G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $SL_2(K)$ is the kernel of the group homomorphism
$$
\det : GL_2(K)\rightarrow K^{\times},
$$
and hence is a normal subgroup.